# How to read a file from Azure Blob Container using Python

Tags: python, json, azure, file, readfile

How can I read files in the Azure blob container using Python?
Im trying to read some JSON files in container for flattening them.

Im new to Azure and dont have much idea about this.
I could connect to the container using "BlobServiceClient".
But, Im not sure how to read the files from a folder in teh container

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you've written and mention any issues you're running into. Also include the version of the SDK you're using.

Comment: @Dave Is that you want to know how to download the file from Azure blob with python?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read a file from Azure blob with python, please refer to the following code

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
connection_string=''
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("<container name>")
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("<blob name>")
blob_client.download_blob().readall() # read blob content as string
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#download-blobs)